# Linux CPU Load always 0

Tags: load, ubuntu-server

I have the following Problem on a vServer (Ubuntu 16.04.3, 64bit, 4 cores, 8GB RAM; openVZ 7):

`$ cat /proc/loadavg
0.00 0.01 0.01 0/1 5719`

Moreover htop shows a CPU load of 0 for each core. Even when starting 4 processes, e.g. Python to create Primes, the overall cpu load is 0. The processes itself shows nearly 100% in htop:

[image: htop with some python processes]

So, any ideas how to solve this problem and get the correct load average again?

Maybe the problem correlates with the following:
I installed i7z (from the default repositorys). Of course it didn't work on a vServer with xeon cores. Then I removed (`apt-get purge i7z`) it. But I'm not sure whether this was the problem.

Btw: When starting htop, top, uptime, /proc/avgload as root I get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all intrested people: The problem was solved two days ago.
The admin of the server told me a few month ago that it isn't a problem with the real server, just with my virtual machine. However, two days ago they did a firmware upgrade. Now it's working again.